# Ruby Shoes, OS X always has error when opening app once packaged

Tags: shoes

Using Shoes (v3.2) to 'Package my App'. Package directory with start script.
Including full copy of shoes.

Opening the packaged app e.g. double click icon, the error console opens:

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
/private/var/folders/20/9wqryt1n76s1f0b9mpq500nc0000gp/T/shoes-upload-gui.40507/upload-gui.shy
```

Visiting the temp directory the shy file is not packaged as part of that directory.

I have tried

- putting the shy into the directory then packaging again works, but the package is now twice as big
- creating a dummy (zero byte) .shy file in the directory and packaging it. This fails with a different error (seems to be trying to unpack the shy and it fails to open - no surprise)
- run the app from command line via shoes-launch e.g `/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/shoes-launch rubystart.rb` console log error never appears
- i have noticed that if run shoes-launch with an additional argument e.g `/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/shoes-launch rubystart.rb blah`  then i get the same `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - blah` error for that file

so it seems like the ruby-shoes packager is trying to call shoes-launch with additional command line parameters (its own shy file?)

anyone come across or fixed this e.g. not needed to put the full shy package within itself?

thanks
Ben

Answer (score 1):

I never fixed the shoes packager. I had to manipulate the final xxx.app as follows

- remove the .shy file
- copy over my ruby files
- ensure gems copied over into lib/gems/... (Note i had issues with gems being picked up via rvm anyhow )
- edit XXX-launch script removing .shy file with my own ruby file

and it all works. there is no error when opening the app.

conclusion: something in the .shy file perhaps? shoes is being upgraded to shoes 4 anyhow, and all this was on shoes 3.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to happen only when trying to package the whole directory.

*(Which also requires creation of a .shy file)*

My workaround would be: **Package a single file** and **copy the rest into the bundled application**.

**I only tryed this on MacOSX** and ***the path inside the App would be "Contents/MacOS/"***.

After doing this everything worked fine, my app is very simple though.